# How to reset htaccess redirects?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, web

I was attempting to make the root of a directory redirect to a folder within it. (Eg. `http://host.com/folderA/` redirect to `http://host.com/folderA/folderB/`

After various attempts of doing this, I kind of broke it..

The folder now redirects to the web root (`http://host.com/`)

And now I can't get the folder back to normal, no matter what I try.. it just keeps redirecting back to the web root. I tried adding a blank htaccess file and tried redirecting it to other folders but it remains redirecting to the root.

I no longer want it to redirect at all because I now just want to link to the folder from an index page. Is there any method of resetting redirects for this folder?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?

Comment: Yes, clearing the cache solved it. Thank you.. though not sure how to mark a comment as answer~